# Python not setting range correctly in plots

Tags: python, plot, ipython

One of the most frustrating things is when you follow a tutorial on a book, and it doesn't work the way it should. I have little idea as to why this is not working.
I'm using IPython right now to make my plots. I have this code:

```
from __future__ import division
fig,ax =subplots()
f=1.0# Hz, signal frequency
fs = 5.0 # Hz, sampling rate (ie. >= 2*f)
t= arange(-1,1+1/fs,1/fs) # sample interval, symmetric
# for convenience later
x= sin(2*pi*f*t)
ax.plot(t,x,'o-' )
ax.set_xlabel('Time' ,fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel(' Amplitude' ,fontsize=18)
```

Which gives the following graph:

[image]

Which is the graph expected in the book. But then when I add this additional code:

```
fig,ax = subplots()
ax.plot(t,x,'o-')
ax.plot(xmin = 1/(4*f)-1/fs*3,
        xmax = 1/(4*f)+1/fs*3,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 1.1 )
ax.set_xlabel('Time',fontsize =18)
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude',fontsize = 18)
```

And I get *the same graph*, even though I'm setting the graph range.
I've tried doing it parameter by parameter, as I found in another question - ax.ymin = 0, ax.ymax = 1.1 , etc....

Why is this happening, and what can I do to view the "zoomed in" graph?

Comment: From which tutorial did you copied the second piece of code ? A would say ax.plot() doesnt have xmin, xmax, etc parameters.

Comment: From "python for signal processing" book, sampling theorem part. Link: http://python-for-signal-processing.blogspot.com/2012/09/investigating-sampling-theorem-in-this.html

The code in the book is a bit different from the one in the website, but neither of them work.

Comment: I think you copied wrongly the code in that link. It says `axis(xmin=, ....)` not `plot(xmin=,...)`. Probalby you should not blame the tutorial but someone else...

Comment: The code I posted is control C+ control V from the book I have in pdf format. The blog I posted I found later, googling the book to see if could post here, where the author seemed to have corrected himself. I blame the book!

Comment: According to the blog, all of the material is available as downloadable IPython notebooks from the  indicated site. So, you could also just use the IPython notebooks directly and save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set limits to the axes you may want to use `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`.

```
fig, ax = subplots()
ax.plot(t, x, 'o-')
ax.set_xlim(1/(4*f)-1/fs*3, 1/(4*f)+1/fs*3)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_xlabel('Time',fontsize =18)
ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude',fontsize = 18)
```

Afaik, `ax.plot()` doesn't have `xmin`, etc keyword arguments, so that they pass unnoticed to the `plot` method. What you see is the result from the previous plot `ax.plot(t,x,'o-')`.

---

A second method to set limits, the one in the [link you indicate](http://python-for-signal-processing.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/investigating-sampling-theorem-in-this.html), is `plt.axis()` .

```
axis(*v, **kwargs)
Convenience method to get or set axis properties.

Calling with no arguments::

  >>> axis()

returns the current axes limits ``[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]``.::

  >>> axis(v)

sets the min and max of the x and y axes, with
``v = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]``.::
```

`axis` set both axis at the same time. see docstring for more information.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I experimented around a bit, and found that this command:

ax.plot(xlim(1/(4*f)-1/fs*3,1/(4*f)+1/fs*3),
        ylim(0,1.1) )

Gives me the result I want, but with a weird line {y = x} crossing the graph, so it seems that it does have some sort of similar parameters. Any clue what's happened in that example?

Comment: No, you are not setting the limits but plotting the result of both methods, that is:  `plot((xmin,xmax), (ymin,ymax))`